# System.Drawing on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, mono, monogame

I'm trying to port a Windows Phone game written in C# using XNA to iOS with MonoGame.

The game plays an animation using MJPEG (Motion Jpeg) and it uses class `Image` to process the frames.

I've created an iOS class library in Visual Studio for Mac 2017... but it looks like `System.Drawing` is not supported.

Am I missing something? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: The DotNet foundation has https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common and some other related info can be found in https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/222

Comment: [CoreCompat.System.Drawing.v2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreCompat.System.Drawing.v2/) might be what you're looking for. The description seems to hit all the relevant points, iOS, Mono...

Comment: @madreflection CoreCompat has been deprecated, you should review https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common from dotnet foundation as it has the widest x-plat support now.

Comment: @SushiHangover - I was unaware of that package. Need to update an old project now. Thanks.

Comment: Just downloaded System.Drawing.Common... but folder xamarinios10 is empty... alias no implementation for iOS

Comment: Better check out alternatives like ImageSharp.